# Logback working for SBT when tests run from Intellij, not working from terminal

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

As the title says, if I run my tests using intellij's 'Run ScalaTests' command, my tests run with logging information properly displayed inside of the intellij terminal.

However, if I attempt to run my tests from the ubuntu terminal using `sbt test` no logs appear.

This seems like extremely bizarre behavior - no settings were changed between running the tests in intellij and running the tests from the command line. The `logback-test.xml` file pretty simple

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>




    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.bitcoins" level="DEBUG"/>

</configuration>
```

Can anyone provide any insight as to why logging does NOT work on the command line, but would work in an intellij?

If you want to take a deeper look at the project configuration, it is open source on github here: https://github.com/christewart/bitcoin-s

Comment: Have you tried to rename `src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` into `src/test/resources/logback.xml` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally removed the following line from my `Build.scala` file

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % logbackV
```